# How to fix this Elasticsearch agent on VM of Azure Kubernetes Services?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, azure-aks

I installed Elasticsearch agent to VM of AKS. There is no data to send to Kibana cloud(which is not install outside AKS). When I tested Elastecsearch modules, there is error:

```
azureuser@aks-agentpool-yyyyyy-0:/var/log/elasticsearch$ sudo metricbeat test modules

Error getting metricbeat modules: 
    module initialization error: 
        5 errors: 
        reading bearer token file: 
        open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory; reading bearer token file: 
        open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory; reading bearer token file: 
        open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory; reading bearer token file: 
        open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory; reading bearer token file: 
        open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory
```

Checked that the error should be based on below code in kubernetes.yml

```
bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
ssl.certificate_authorities:
  - /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-ca.crt
```

How can I create secret on Azure VM to solve this problem?

---

**Supplements**

I follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh to connect to VMSS / VM then install Metricbeat already. But there is no data to send to Kibana.

Below are the steps that I performed:

```
# CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP=$(az aks show --resource-group XXX --name YYY --query nodeResourceGroup -o tsv)
# SCALE_SET_NAME=$(az vmss list --resource-group $CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP --query [0].name -o tsv)

# az vmss extension set  \
--resource-group $CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP \
--vmss-name $SCALE_SET_NAME \
--name VMAccessForLinux \
--publisher Microsoft.OSTCExtensions \
--version 1.4 \
--protected-settings "{\"username\":\"azureuser\", \"ssh_key\":\"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)\"}"

# az vmss update-instances --instance-ids '*' \
--resource-group $CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP \
--name $SCALE_SET_NAME

# kubectl get nodes -o wide
# az vm list --resource-group $CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP -o table
# az vm list-ip-addresses --resource-group $CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP -o table
# kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 -it --rm aks-ssh --image=debian

// Inside aks-ssh
apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-client -y

// Open another terminal then copy SSH key
# kubectl cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa $(kubectl get pod -l run=aks-ssh -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}'):/id_rsa

// Inside aks-ssh again
#chmod 0600 id_rsa
// Connect to vmss/VM:
#ssh -i id_rsa azureuser@10.240.0.4

// -- in VMSS --
// Download Metricbeat(use deb)
# curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/metricbeat/metricbeat-7.5.0-amd64.deb
# sudo dpkg -i metricbeat-7.5.0-amd64.deb

// Modify metricbeat.yml:
# sudo nano /etc/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml
// Add below in “Elastic Cloud” section
cloud.id: "<--id-->"
cloud.auth: "<--auth-->"

// Enable Kubernetes
# sudo metricbeat modules enable kubernetes

// Modify kubernetes.yml
# sudo nano /etc/metricbeat/modules.d/kubernetes.yml

// Start Metricbeat
# sudo metricbeat setup
# sudo service metricbeat start
```

Comment: do you have that file specified in "Mounts:" section of the output of `kubectl describe pod <your_pod_name>`  ?  Can you access that file from pods?  Are permissions correct?

Comment: hi @Nick, I did not install Elasticsearch as a pod but install on the VM/VMSS. Supplemented steps that I perform for your reference, thanks.

Comment: Why you install the Elasticsearch in the VMSS/VM? Actually, they do not have the public IP so that you cannot access it through the Internet. And as I see, the image of Elasticsearch for Kubernetes contains the ca.crt inside it. If necessary, you can copy it from the image.